# Split line into lines by spaces

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Having

```
<Route key="product" path={`${match.url}/:productId`} component={ProductEditor} />
```

How to get the following automatically?

```
<Route
    key="product"
    path={`${match.url}/:productId`}
    component={ProductEditor}
/>
```

I am using vim extension, but standard vim tricks don't seem to work here (`:s/ /\n/g` etc..)

So much time wasted every time!
Thanks

Comment: Select all by CTRL A and do  CTRL+ALT+L

Answer (score 0):

As @sailesh says `ctrl+alt+L` refactoring code according to code style settings. To change them you can go to *File->Settings->Editor->Code Style* and set wrapping as you need for any language. e.g. for XML: change "Wrap attributes" to Wrap always.

Comment: This works for Intellij, but Webstorm has same settings I guess

Comment: Thanks, but what ctrl-alt-l stands for? I think I have most shortcuts remapped.. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't help with JSX at least :( Both forms - single line and multiline are acceptable for the formatter so it doesn't change the format

Comment: I think probably some sort of macros replacing in selection according to regex might help

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko do you have JSX in code style settings?

Comment: No I don't.. do you?